# WooCommerce "wc_get_product" with custom field sorting

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to filter this WooCommerce output with products which have a certain custom field.
With the code beneath all product packages are shown, but I want shown only special ones, sorted out by a custom field value.

```
 <?php
    foreach ( $packages as $key => $package ) :
    $product = wc_get_product( $package );
    if (!$product->is_type( array( 'job_package', 'job_package_subscription' ) ) ||!$product->is_purchasable() ) {
    continue;
    }
?>
```